# Print a map as a sequence C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, maps

I am trying to fill out this function, however I am having some trouble with it. It takes in a map with a long, and vector(long) and a long as a parameter.

The function and its specifications are here down below.

> Input is a collatz map (map(long, vector(long)) and a long
>        returns a vector, the collatz sequence for that number
>        Operation. As you iterate through the collatz sequence
>        - uses collatz_next if the element in question is not in the map
>        - if the element *is* in the map, copies the sequence from the map
>        to the end of the current sequence and ends.

```
vector<long> collatz_sequence(map<long, vector<long>> &m, long number) {
// This is what i've tried. 
vector<long> my_vec = m[number];
return my_vec;
}
```

This is the other function that it uses:

```
long collatz_next(long n) {
long return_value = 0;
if (n > 0) {
    if (n%2 == 0) {
        return_value = n/2;
    } else {
        return_value = (3*n) + 1;
        //return return_value;
    }
} else {
    throw range_error("error");
}
return return_value;
}
```

Functioning code sample:

```
map<long, vector<long> > m;
vector<long> v = collatz_sequence(m,16);
vector<long> ans = {8,4,2,1};
ASSERT_EQ(v, ans);
```

Comment: Can you post a fully functioning code sample?

Comment: map<long, vector<long> > m;
vector<long> v = collatz_sequence(m,16);
vector<long> ans = {8,4,2,1};
ASSERT_EQ(v, ans);

Comment: @LThode added it to the code

Comment: the correct output should be is {8,4,2,1};

Answer (score 0):

There is no call to `collatz_next()` from `collatz_sequence()` anyway. So there cannot be any data in the map `m`.

The trouble you mentioned can come from the fact, that there will be no `vector<>` object assigned to `v`. Unless you don't specify what error exactly happens it's hard to tell.